# How to interpolate data on the surface of the Earth outside the range of data?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, interpolation, cartopy

I have the following code to plot an arbitrary dataset on Earth:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

nn = 360.  # used to make lons negative when > 180.
lats = [40, 37, 33, -29.7, -34.4, -35.3,47,-85,64,18]
lons = [-105.30, -7.0, -233.7, -54.0, 19.22, 149.0, 47, -85, 64, 18]
data = [0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10,7,8,6,8]

# Create a meshgrid for interpolation
xi = np.linspace(-180, 180, 100)
yi = np.linspace(-90, 90, 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# Perform 2D interpolation
zi = griddata((lons, lats), data, (xi, yi), method='linear')

# Create a Cartopy PlateCarree projection centered at lon = 0
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0))

# Add coastlines and gridlines
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

# Set extent of the plot
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())


# Create color plot
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, shading='auto', cmap='viridis')

# Create scatter plot with data as color
scatter = ax.scatter(lons, lats, c=data, cmap='viridis', s=100,\
                     edgecolors='black',linewidths=1,\
                     transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

print(lons)

# Add colorbar
cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter, label='Number of monkeys (Monkeys /$m^2$)', ax=ax, shrink=0.7, pad = .1)
cbar.mappable.set_clim(0, 10)

# Add title
plt.title('2D Interpolation Colorplot with\nScatter Plot (PlateCarree Projection)')
plt.show()
```

That generates the following plot:

[image: Interpolated data]

But the problem is that this interpolation does not cover the white space in the figure. It seems like I need a spherical interpolation. Does anyone have any experience with that? Thank you!!!

Comment: To cover the white space in the figure, would you not need extrapolation instead of interpolation?

Comment: If you think of it as interpolating on the surface of a sphere, we the white space on the figure is always between several points on the surface of the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the Rbf:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
 
lats = [40, 37, 33, -29.7, -34.4, -35.3,47,-85,64,18]
lons = [-105.30, -7.0, -233.7, -54.0, 19.22, 149.0, 47, -85, 64, 18]
data = [0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10,7,8,6,8]
 
# Create a meshgrid for interpolation
xi = np.linspace(-180, 180, 100)
yi = np.linspace(-90, 90, 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
 
# Different functions for the spherical interpolation:
# 'linear': Linear radial basis function
# 'multiquadric': Multiquadric radial basis function
# 'inverse': Inverse radial basis function
# 'gaussian': Gaussian radial basis function
# 'cubic': Cubic radial basis function
# 'quintic': Quintic radial basis function
# 'thin_plate': Thin-plate spline radial basis function
 
# Perform 2D interpolation using Rbf for spherical interpolation
rbf = Rbf(lons, lats, data, function='inverse')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)
 
# Create a Cartopy PlateCarree projection centered at lon = 0
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0))
 
# Add coastlines and gridlines
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
 
# Set extent of the plot
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
 
# Create color plot
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, shading='auto', cmap='viridis')
 
# Create scatter plot with data as color
scatter = ax.scatter(lons, lats, c=data, cmap='viridis', s=100,\
                     edgecolors='black',linewidths=1,\
                     transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
 
# Add colorbar
cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter, label='Number of monkeys (Monkeys /$m^2$)', ax=ax, shrink=0.7, pad = .1)
cbar.mappable.set_clim(0, 10)
 
# Add title
plt.title('2D Interpolation Colorplot with\nScatter Plot (PlateCarree Projection)')
plt.savefig('/path/to/figures/MapInterpolation.png', dpi = 300)
 
plt.show()
```

That Radial Basis Function (Rbf> [scipy.interpolate.Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html)) interpolates well in the surface of a sphere. I made a point of adding the different functions one can use in the comment above the Rbf call. For me, the 'inverse' was the one that made the most sense visually:

[image]